# How can I give option Menu in Application?

Tags: android

I want to give Option menu in my application and also that menu are clickable. If I click any menu than it will open another activity. So, please help me for this. In my application there is many class or activity i want to put this optionmenu in every activity of my application. here i try with this kind of code.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MenuItem dashboard = menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Dashboard");
        MenuItem roles = menu.add(0, 2, 2, "Roles");
        MenuItem profiles = menu.add(0, 3, 3, "Profiles");
        MenuItem move = menu.add(0, 4, 4, "Move Product");
        MenuItem assignedproduct = menu.add(0, 5, 5, "Assigned Product Report");
        MenuItem salesreport = menu.add(0, 6, 6, "Sales Report");
        MenuItem salesreturn = menu.add(0, 7, 7, "Sales Return");
        MenuItem purchasereport = menu.add(0, 8,8, "Purchase Report");
        MenuItem logout = menu.add(0, 9, 9, "Logout");

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
```

Comment: Post your code what you have tried till now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `onCreateOptionsMenu` function in each activity of your app. that's the only way

Answer (score 0):

To give the click functionality to menu items, you will have to override the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method. Then give those `MenuItems` their respective action based on their item id as follows...

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case 1:
        // give action to the menu item which id is 1
        return true;

    case 2:
        // give action to the menu item which id is 2
        return true;

    case 3:
        // give action to the menu item which id is 3
        return true;

    case 4:
        // give action to the menu item which id is 4
        return true;

     ..........
     ..........

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I doesn't understand how i can give conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your activities should have same menu, best way is move creating menu in superclass. . Name it `MenuActivity`, for example. In this class override `onCreateOptionsMenu` for creating menu and `onOptionsItemSelected` for handling user taps. Then just inherit all your activities from `MenuActivity`.